# Java Scanner delimiter doesn't split the last section

Tags: java, file-io, java.util.scanner, delimiter

```
/* txt file
Rolling Stone#Jann Wenner#Bi-Weekly#Boston#9000
Rolling Stone#Jann Wenner#Bi-Weekly#Philadelphia#8000
Rolling Stone#Jann Wenner#Bi-Weekly#London#10000
The Economist#John Micklethwait#Weekly#New York#42000
The Economist#John Micklethwait#Weekly#Washington#29000
Nature#Philip Campbell#Weekly#Pittsburg#4000
Nature#Philip Campbell#Weekly#Berlin#6000
*/   


 public class Zines {

            public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
                Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("txt.file"));
                input.useDelimiter("#|\n|\r|\r\n");

                while(input.hasNext()) {  
                    String title = input.next();
                    String author = input.next();
                    String publisher = input.next();
                    String city = input.next();
                    String line = input.nextLine();
                    //int dist = Integer.valueOf(line);

                    System.out.println(line); 
        }
        }
    }
```

Output is:

```
"#9000
"#8000
"#10000
"#42000
"#29000
"#4000
"#6000
```

Output 2:

```
9000
Rolling Stone
("Exception in thread "main") Jann Wenner
Weekly
Washington
4000
Nature
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The question here is why does the #'s still appear after using the delimiter?

Because you are using [`Scanner#nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) to read the last part. It wouldn't consider the delimiter. It will read the complete remaining text after the previously read token, and not the next token.

So, if the previous token read is `Boston`, the remaining text - `#9000`, will be read by `nextLine()`.
You should use [`scanner#next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) instead.

```
String line = input.next();
```

Comment: Replaced it! And the first row i get is fine but it messes up when it re-loops and the values i get back aren't correct! I guess since i didn't have nextLine() it misses the line separation

Comment: @BlazingApu. Yeah that's the problem. You can change your delimiter in that case. Use a pattern like - `#|\n|\r|\r\n`.

Comment: @BlazingApu. You're welcome :) You can mark the answer as accepted by clicking the tick mark besides the answer.